# How to get a string between two short strings in a Dictionary... Python

Tags: python, string, dictionary

Good morning.
I have a dictionary (in python) with keys as names and values as dna sequences ('acgt...'). I need to get from the values of this dictionary all the strings between two specific three letters ('atg' as starting point and 'taa','aag' or 'tga' as finish points). I tried several things and I did not get nothing like I want it. And I cant find any help on the internet. Someone can help me? Thanks

This is what I tried:

I just know how to get all characters between two different specify indices, but that's not what I want: Here is a very small example:

```
opts= {'id1':'acgatgctagcagctagcacagctagaatgccgatgacacacagctaatggcagttaaacatcgaca‌​gctctcgcgcgcaagcgatacaccagctagaccagattaaaag', 'id2':'atgagacacacacacacagggggggcggcgcgcatacatttttacacacatacattaaatgacacagccacag‌​cgacagccagccagccatttttattttttaaagatgcaccgatacacaca'}; 
keys=list(opts.keys())
print(keys)
value=list(opts.values())
print(value)
i='atg'
j='taa' 
for i in range (len(value)): 
  for j in range(i): 
    print(value[j:i])
```

Comment: Please post whatever you have tried.

Comment: What did you try, which didn't work?

Comment: And if you could set an example of the strings and the result you'd expect to get, even better!

Comment: please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please, @Francisco, add the example to the original question (edit).

Comment: And try and read your own text as if you knew nothing about the problem at hand (which we don't know), and ask yourself if you are giving us enough information about what is that you want, what is not working of your code, what is what you would like to obtain instead.

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved by using the `find` function of Python. Since your start is fixed and end can be one of the three strings, we will loop over the input string to find the one which matches.

```
str = "acgatgctagcagctagcacagctagaatgccgatgacacacagctaatggcagttaaacatcgaca‌​gctctcgcgcgcaagcgatacaccagctagaccagattaaaag"

def str_between( str, first, last ):
    start = str.find( first ) + len( first )
    end = str.find( last[0], start )
    index = 1
    while(end == -1 and index < len(last) ):
            end = str.find( last[index], start )
            index= index + 1
    if end !=-1:
            return str[start:end]
    else:
            return ''
```

call this function with two parameters just as described below. You have to pass the value for each key as input.

```
output = str_between( str, "atg", ["taa","aag","tga"] )
```

Comment: Thanks! your code returned me an error:

Line 29: NameError: name 's' is not defined
line 29: return s[start:end]

Comment: What is the error ? I have changed a bit. Check again. I ran it didn't give error. See if string is getting copied properly. Also I have not done error handling if there is no match. Take care of that.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sharad... One last question, I hope I do not bother too much. As you can see in this string there are several starting points and several end points. How can I get the string for all the possible fragments between starting and end points. Do I explain myself? Thanks.

Comment: You can do that. Explore findall() method of Python's re module. You can find index of all the occurrence of a substring inside a string. Do that for your start string and end string. That will give you all the start and end points. Those values you can use to get the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
    d = {'id1':'acgatgctagcagctagcacagctagaatgccgatgacacacagctaatggcagttaaacatcgaca‌​gctctcgcgcgcaagcgatacaccagctagaccagattaaaag',
         'id2':'atgagacacacacacacagggggggcggcgcgcatacatttttacacacatacattaaatgacacagccacag‌​cgacagccagccagccatttttattttttaaagatgcaccgatacacaca'}

    for k,v in d.items():
        dna = re.split(r'\W',v)
        for el in dna:
            if el:
             mo= re.search(r'(atg.*taa|atg.*tga|atg.*aag)', el)
             if mo:
                 print(mo.group(1))

    atgagacacacacacacagggggggcggcgcgcatacatttttacacacatacattaa
    atgctagcagctagcacagctagaatgccgatgacacacagctaatggcagttaa
```